# Getting warning : Exposed name does not exist: Volume but I did expose volume to script why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SettingsMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
    public Dropdown resolutionDropDown;

    [SerializeField]
    private Slider _volumeSlider;
    [SerializeField]
    private Dropdown _dropDownQuality;

    private Resolution[] resolutions;

    private void Start()
    {
        resolutions = Screen.resolutions;
        resolutionDropDown.ClearOptions();

        List<string> options = new List<string>();

        int currentResolutionIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            string option = resolutions[i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height;
            options.Add(option);

            if (resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width &&
                resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
            {
                currentResolutionIndex = i;
            }
        }

        resolutionDropDown.AddOptions(options);
        resolutionDropDown.value = currentResolutionIndex;
        resolutionDropDown.RefreshShownValue();
    }

    public void SetVolume()
    {
        float volume = _volumeSlider.value;
        Debug.Log("Volume " + volume);
        audioMixer.SetFloat("Volume", volume);
    }

    public void SetQuality()
    {
        int qualityIndex = _dropDownQuality.value;
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }

    public void SetFullScreen()
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = !Screen.fullScreen;
    }
}
```

The warning is on line 48 :

```
audioMixer.SetFloat("Volume", volume);
```

Screenshot of the Audio Mixer inspector settings I did expose to the Volume :

[image: Audio Mixer Inspector settings]

After exposing there is the arrow pointing to the right above the Volume :

[image: After exposed]

But still getting the warning when running the game and changing the Volume slider.
It should change the volume in the audio mixer but instead it's showing this warning.

Comment: A solution I found in this nice site tutorial : https://johnleonardfrench.com/articles/the-right-way-to-make-a-volume-slider-in-unity-using-logarithmic-conversion/

Comment: Check if the name of the exposed parameter is actually "Volume" and not something else. You can do this by looking at the exposed parameters and even rename them to fit your liking. [Read about it in the official documentation.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioMixerInspectors.html)